# Unable to Test the SimpleJdbcCall execute Call

Tags: mocking, mockito

I need to Test the following class

```
@Repository
public class CustomerContactDaoImpl implements CustomerContactDao {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "rcx_jdbc_template")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public void insertCustomerContact(Contact contact) {
        SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("insert_contact");
        try {
            call.execute(new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("customerid", contact.getCustomerID()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

**MyTest Class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustContDaoImplTest {
     @Mock
       private SimpleJdbcCallFactory simpleJdbcCallFactory;
     @Mock
       private DataSource dataSource;
     @Mock
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
     @Autowired
     @InjectMocks
       private CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;
     @Before
     public void setUp() throws SQLException {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

     @Test
       public void testinsertCustomerContact() throws Exception {
           Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);
            SimpleJdbcCall mockedSimpleJdbcCall  = Mockito.mock(SimpleJdbcCall.class);
            mockedSimpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("insert_contact");
            Mockito.when(mockedSimpleJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(any(Map.class));
            customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);
       }
}

@Component
class SimpleJdbcCallFactory {
   public SimpleJdbcCall create(JdbcTemplate template) {
       return new SimpleJdbcCall(template);
   }
}
```

**getting the following exception**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> dao.test.CustContDaoImpl.testinsertCustomerContact(CustContDaoImpl.java:68)



    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:283)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:363)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198)
    atdao.test.CustContDaoImpl.testinsertCustomerContact(CustContDaoImpl.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

I have tried as

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustContDaoImplTest {
     @Mock
       private SimpleJdbcCallFactory simpleJdbcCallFactory;
     @Mock
       private DataSource dataSource;
     @Mock
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @InjectMocks
       private CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;

     @Before
     public void setUp() throws SQLException {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

     @Test
       public void testinsertCustomerContact() throws Exception {
           Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);
            Map<String, Object> resMap = new HashMap<>();
            Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.call(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(resMap);
            customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);
     }
}

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:289)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(CallMetaDataProviderFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext.initializeMetaData(CallMetaDataContext.java:286)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:303)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.compile(AbstractJdbcCall.java:288)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcCall.java:348)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:363)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198)
    at com.nrg.bccd.dao.impl.CustomerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(CustomerContactDaoImpl.java:65)
     dao.test.CustContDaoImplTest.testinsertCustomerContact(CustContDaoImplTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: `InvalidUseOfMatchersException` is because of the improper use of `any()`  argument matcher in `.thenReturn(any(Map.class));` That is not allowed.

Comment: Chnaged it to          Map<String, Object> resMap =  Mockito.mock(Map.class);
         Mockito.when(mockedSimpleJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(resMap);
but still same exception

Comment: Why do you keep overriding the mocked instance with an actual instance?

Comment: I am new to Mockitto and not sure

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, your exception comes likely from trying to define behaviour on something that is not a mock.

Assuming your code looks something like this (after your changes):

```
@Test
public void testinsertCustomerContact() throws Exception {
    Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);

    SimpleJdbcCall mockedSimpleJdbcCall = Mockito.mock(SimpleJdbcCall.class);

    // this line is causing the problem
    mockedSimpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("insert_contact");

    Map<String, Object> resMap = Mockito.mock(Map.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedSimpleJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(resMap); 

    customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);
}
```

then you still have overriden the mock, when you created a new `SimpleJdbcCall` object.

---

**However all that does not seem to be the correct way, as it does not match to your class under test.**

Using `@Autowired` / `@Component` with the `MockitoJUnitRunner` won't have any effect as `Mockito` is unaware of these annotations.

What you need to do is define the behaviour on your `JdbcTemplate` mock, so that 
`SimpleJdbcCall` can work properly. I took a short look at the spring sourcecode and based on what I see you need to (at least) define behaviour on the [`call`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L1126) method, which is used in the [`AbstractJdbcCall#executeCallInternal`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/AbstractJdbcCall.java#L401) method.

So changeing the test to something like this might work ...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustContDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerContactDaoImpl customerContactDaoImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testinsertCustomerContact() throws Exception {

        Contact contact = Mockito.mock(Contact.class);

        Map<String, Object> resMap = new HashMap<>();
        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.call(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(resMap);

        customerContactDaoImpl.insertCustomerContact(contact);
    }
}
```

*Note: Mocking a `Map` is never really necessary. Instead simply create a map and add the required content into it.*

---

However an easier approach would be to refactor the class so you can simply replace the newly created instance of `SimpleJdbcCall`. Your example code shows a `SimpleJdbcCallFactory` class which creates such a object, however there does not seem to be any relation to your class under test.

If refactoring is not an option using `PowerMockito.whenNew` functionality might also we worth considering.

---

That said - In the end I would recommend that you rather focus on an Integration test with a `real` database behind, rather than using mocking here.

Comment: I have tried as mentioned above and i am getting , java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No DataSource specified

Comment: i have updated my question with the actual exception

Comment: As mentioned you need to mock all interactions with the `JdbcTemplate`. Apparently behaviour for the `getDatasource` method needs to be defined as well. You'll likely run into more of these issues if you continue that way. You will have to check the spring sourcecode and see how it interacts with the mocks.